# Label Imperfect Information dashed line in tree

Tags: labels, tikz-trees, trees

I am trying to add two labels, one over each of the two dash lines. Each time I add some variation in code at the place I created the lines, the corresponding label shows up at the top of the figure. What am I missing?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\small
\begin{tikzpicture}[thin,
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=60mm},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=25mm},
  level 3/.style={sibling distance=15mm},
  every circle node/.style={minimum size=1.5mm,inner sep=1.25mm}]

  \node[circle,draw,label=above:$N$] (root) {}
    child { node [circle,draw,label=above:$1$] {}
      child { 
        node[circle,draw,label=below:$A$] (node-A) {}
          child {
            node {$8,3$}
            edge from parent
              node[left] {$S$}}
          child {
             node {$6,5$}
             edge from parent
               node[right] {$\neg S$}}
          edge from parent
            node[left] {$C$}}
      child { 
        node[circle,draw,label=below:$A$] (node-B) {}
          child {
            node {$5,8$}
            edge from parent
              node[left] {$S$}}
          child {
             node {$2,7$}
             edge from parent
               node[right] {$\neg S$}}
          edge from parent
            node[right] {$\neg C$}}
       edge from parent
         node[left] {$Type I$}}
    child { node [circle,draw,label=above:$2$] {}
      child { 
        node[circle,draw,label=below:$A$] (node-C) {}
          child {
            node {$7,6$}
            edge from parent
              node[left] {$S$}}
          child {
             node {$3,4$}
             edge from parent
               node[right] {$\neg S$}}
          edge from parent
            node[left] {$C$}}
      child { 
        node[circle,draw,label=below:$A$] (node-D) {}
          child {
            node {$1,0$}
            edge from parent
              node[left] {$S$}}
          child {
             node {$0,1$}
             edge from parent
               node[right] {$\neg S$}}
          edge from parent
            node[right] {$\neg C$}}
       edge from parent
         node[right] {$Type II$}};
  \draw [dashed,out=45,in=135] (node-A) to (node-C) 
  [dashed,out=45,in=135] (node-B) to (node-D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Extensive-form game}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) As an aside, you do not need to place the contents of nodes inside `$`, `{$Type I$}` for example should probably be `{Type I}` or you can use normal text commands like `\textit{foo}` to obtain italics.

Comment: @DaiBowen Thanks! I appreciate the suggestion. Always nice to clean up code where I can. Got any guesses on the labeling? I'm well and truly stumped.

Comment: `\draw [dashed,out=45,in=135] (node-A) to node [midway,above] {Text above} (node-C);` does the job I think.

Comment: @DaiBowen Oh!, that makes sense that it goes between the nodes. Thank you again, you've been a big help.

Answer (score 2):

Just because it is a tree ...

Forest makes it possible to specify trees very concisely and cleanly, once the configuration is set up in the tree's preamble.

Note that this requires Forest version 2.1:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  /tikz/every edge quotes/.style={midway, above},
  my edge label/.style n args=3{
  %  if={>On={n}{1}}{edge label={node [midway, left, #1] {#2}}}{edge label={node [midway, right, #1] {#3}}}
    % Sašo: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34010033#34010033
    edge label/.process={On=?}{n}{1}{node [midway, left, #1] {#2}}{node [midway, right, #1] {#3}}
  },
  my inverse edge label/.style={
    my edge label={}{$#1$}{$\lnot #1$}
  },
  my arc label/.style n args=2{
    tikz+={
      \draw [dashed, out=135, in=45] () edge ["#1"] (#2);
    }
  },
  for tree={math content, l sep*=3, s sep*=3},
  before typesetting nodes={
    where n children=0{% terminal nodes
      my inverse edge label=S
    }{% non-terminal nodes
      if level=2{
        label/.wrap pgfmath arg={below:$#1$}{content()},
        my inverse edge label=C
      }{
        label/.wrap pgfmath arg={above:$#1$}{content()},
        my edge label={font=\itshape}{Type I}{Type II}
      },
      content=,
      draw,
      circle,
      inner sep=1.25mm,
    }
  },
  [N
    [1
      [A
        [{8,3}]
        [{6,5}]
      ]
      [A
        [{5,8}]
        [{2,7}]
      ]
    ]
    [2
      [A, my arc label={label here}{!r11}
        [{7,6}]
        [{3,4}]
      ]
      [A, my arc label={label there}{!r12}
        [{1,0}]
        [{0,1}]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Forest]

Answer (score 2):

You only need add a node to dashed curve :). For example:

```
\draw[dashed,out=45,in=135] (node-A) to node[above] {label left}  (node-C)
                            (node-B) to node[above] {label right} (node-D);
```

or by use of Tikz library `quotes`:

```
\draw[dashed,out=45,in=135] (node-A) to ["label left"](node-C)
                            (node-B) to ["label right"](node-D);
```

[image]

Complete MWE for second case is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, quotes}% <-- changed

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[thin,
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=60mm},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=25mm},
  level 3/.style={sibling distance=15mm},
  every circle node/.style={minimum size=1.5mm,inner sep=1.25mm},
  font = \small
                    ]

  \node[circle,draw,label=above:$N$] (root) {}
    child { node [circle,draw,label=above:$1$] {}
      child {
        node[circle,draw,label=below:$A$] (node-A) {}
          child {
            node {$8,3$}
            edge from parent
              node[left] {$S$}}
          child {
             node {$6,5$}
             edge from parent
               node[right] {$\neg S$}}
          edge from parent
            node[left] {$C$}}
      child {
        node[circle,draw,label=below:$A$] (node-B) {}
          child {
            node {$5,8$}
            edge from parent
              node[left] {$S$}}
          child {
             node {$2,7$}
             edge from parent
               node[right] {$\neg S$}}
          edge from parent
            node[right] {$\neg C$}}
       edge from parent
         node[left] {$Type I$}}
    child { node [circle,draw,label=above:$2$] {}
      child {
        node[circle,draw,label=below:$A$] (node-C) {}
          child {
            node {$7,6$}
            edge from parent
              node[left] {$S$}}
          child {
             node {$3,4$}
             edge from parent
               node[right] {$\neg S$}}
          edge from parent
            node[left] {$C$}}
      child {
        node[circle,draw,label=below:$A$] (node-D) {}
          child {
            node {$1,0$}
            edge from parent
              node[left] {$S$}}
          child {
             node {$0,1$}
             edge from parent
               node[right] {$\neg S$}}
          edge from parent
            node[right] {$\neg C$}}
       edge from parent
         node[right] {$Type II$}};
\draw[dashed,out=45,in=135] (node-A) to ["label left"]  (node-C) % <-- changed
                            (node-B) to ["label right"] (node-D);% <-- changed
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Extensive-form game}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Edit: `istgame` v2.0

The [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) provides a new macro `\xtCinfoset` to draw curved (even skewed) information sets.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{istgame}    
\begin{document}   

\begin{istgame}[font=\small]
\tikzset{decision node/.style={ellipse node,inner sep=3.5pt}}
\setistmathTF*101 % action labels in italics
\xtdistance{15mm}{60mm}
\istroot(0){N}
  \istb{Type I}[al]   \istb{Type II}[ar]  \endist
\setistmathTF111 % all important labels are in math mode
\xtdistance{15mm}{25mm}
\istroot(1)(0-1){1}
  \istb{C}[al]  \istb{\neg C}[ar]  \endist
\istroot(2)(0-2){2}
  \istb{C}[al]  \istb{\neg C}[ar]  \endist
\xtdistance{15mm}{15mm}
\istroot(11)(1-1)<-90>{A}
  \istb{S}[l]{8,3}  \istb{\neg S}[r]{6,5}  \endist
\istroot(12)(1-2)<-90>{A}
  \istb{S}[l]{5,8}  \istb{\neg S}[r]{2,7}  \endist
\istroot(21)(2-1)<-90>{A}
  \istb{S}[l]{7,6}  \istb{\neg S}[r]{3,4}  \endist
\istroot(22)(2-2)<-90>{A}
  \istb{S}[l]{1,0}  \istb{\neg S}[r]{0,1}  \endist
% curved information set
\xtCInfoset(11)(21)<1.4>{label here}
% skewed curved information set
\xtCInfoset(12)!.75!(22)<1.8>{label there}
\end{istgame}    
\end{document}
```

#### Original answer

To draw information sets, you can use `\xtInfoset` with the [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}   

\begin{istgame}[font=\small]
\tikzset{decision node/.style={ellipse node,inner sep=3.5pt}}
\xtdistance{15mm}{60mm}
\istroot(0){$N$}
  \istb{Type I}[al]
  \istb{Type II}[ar]
  \endist
\xtdistance{15mm}{25mm}
\istroot(1)(0-1){1}
  \istb{C}[al]
  \istb{\neg C}[ar]
  \endist
\istroot(2)(0-2){2}
  \istb{C}[al]
  \istb{\neg C}[ar]
  \endist
\xtdistance{15mm}{15mm}
\istroot(11)(1-1)<-90>{A}
  \istb{S}[l]{8,3}
  \istb{\neg S}[r]{6,5}
  \endist
\istroot(12)(1-2)<-90>{A}
  \istb{S}[l]{5,8}
  \istb{\neg S}[r]{2,7}
  \endist
\istroot(21)(2-1)<-90>{A}
  \istb{S}[l]{7,6}
  \istb{\neg S}[r]{3,4}
  \endist
\istroot(22)(2-2)<-90>{A}
  \istb{S}[l]{1,0}
  \istb{\neg S}[r]{0,1}
  \endist
\xtInfoset[thin,dashed,bend left=45](11)(21){label here}[yshift=37pt]
\xtInfoset[thin,dashed,bend left=45](12)(22){label there}[yshift=35pt]
\end{istgame}
\end{document}
```